# How do I solve flask authentication?

Tags: python, flask, jwt, endpoint, flask-restful

I am trying to do authentication in my flask app. After loggin in the user is redirected to protected endpoint /forms. But everytime I am getting redirected I get message

```
{
    "msg": "Missing Authorization Header"
}
```

Right now I am doing authorization via params but it is not good aproach.

````
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key_here'
jwt = JWTManager(app)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        if not username or not password:
            return jsonify({"msg": "Missing username or password"}), 400

        if authenticate(username, password):
            access_token = create_access_token(identity={'username': username})
            tokens[username] = access_token
            response = redirect(url_for('forms', username=username, access_token=access_token))
            response.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token
            return response
            return redirect(url_for('forms', username=username, access_token=access_token))
        else:
            return jsonify({"msg": "Invalid username or password"}), 401
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

def check_key_and_token(username, access_token):
    if username not in tokens.keys():
        return jsonify({"msg": "Invalid username"}), 401
    if not access_token:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Missing token"}), 401
    if access_token == tokens[username]:
        return True
    else:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Invalid token"}), 401

@app.route('/<username>/forms', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@jwt_required()
def forms(username):
    access_token = request.args.get('access_token')
    if check_key_and_token(username, access_token) is not True:
        return check_key_and_token(username, access_token)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_text = request.form.get('input_text')
        return redirect(url_for('weather', username=username, access_token=access_token, city=input_text))
    else:
        return render_template('forms.html')
    ```

Does anybody know how to make it work?
````

Comment: You might need csrf token in forms. Also, you might want to send `Set-Cookie` header instructions in your responses after successful login so that session cookie persists on the next requests

Comment: you have 2 returns in your login method, the second code path is unreachable. for the login route itself, just handle the login, don't do a redirect

Comment: and then in the forms route, handle your authentication logic, probably with a common login template

Answer (score 1):

There is a general principle in security that should not reinvent something, because you're likely to mess it up (not that you're bad at it, but it's too easy to screw it up). I'd recommend using a package like flask_login for this.